# How can I call a function of a child view from the parent view in swiftUI to change a @state variable?

Tags: swift, swiftui, swiftui-state

I'm trying to get into swift/swiftui but I'm really struggling with this one:

I have a `MainView` containing a `ChildView`. The `ChildView` has a function `update` to fetch the data to display from an external source and assign it to a `@State data` variable.

I'd like to be able to trigger `update` from `MainView` in order to update `data`.

I've experienced that `update` is in fact called, however, `data` is reset to the initial value upon this call.

The summary of what I have:

```swift
struct ChildView: View {
    
    @State var data: Int = 0

     var body: some View {
       Text("\(data)")

        Button(action: update) {
            Text("update") // works as expected 
        }
     }

    func update() {
        // fetch data from external source 
        data = 42
    }
}
```

```swift
struct MainView: View {
    var child = ChildView()
 
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
           child
           
           Button(action: {
              child.update()
           }) {
              Text("update")  // In fact calls the function, but doesn't set the data variable to the new value
           }
        }
    }
}
```

When googling for a solution, I only came across people suggesting to move `update` and `data` to `MainView` and then pass a binding of `data` to `ChildView`.

However, following this logic I'd have to blow up `MainView` by adding all the data access logic in there. My point of having `ChildView` at all is to break up code into smaller chunks and to reuse `ChildView` including the data access methods in other parent views, too.
I just cannot believe there's no way of doing this in SwiftUI.

Comment: You should try the Apple SwiftUI tutorials. It isn’t like other frameworks. You can’t hold on to the view in a variable and expect it to work like others work. You can reuse the data that the views can react to but not the views, SwiftUI recreates them and reloads when it deems necessary.

Comment: I'm afraid you'll have to be more specific with me. What's the general concept to achieve what I want in SwiftUI? Can you give me a buzzword or point me to a specific tutorial?

Comment: What you want isn’t viable with SwiftUI. The “Apple SwiftUI tutorials” will give you the basics.

Comment: Then what's the Swift way to have interacting modules? I've been searching for this for quite a while now. Merely referring me to "the apple tutorials" isn't helpful at all.

Comment: That is literally what they are called, if you Google those exact words you will get a set of tutorials Apple has provided, the very first link. You can’t have views in variables as you are trying to do.

Comment: 1. I know where to find those tutorials and I've been practicing with them before. What I don't know, what I didn't find out using them, and what I'm asking for here is how to have interacting views or – alternatively – how to achieve the same result by other means. 2. Other tutorials clearly say one can have views in variables, e.g. [here](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/swiftui/how-to-store-views-as-properties) and 3. Why would you even comment if you at least pretend to know to help me but don't want to?!

Comment: This setup will not work, you have to change the data using models and use the appropriate wrappers. There is no way to do what you want because SwiftUI hides what it is doing, the instance of the view you are holding on to does not know when to update because it is outside a ViewBuilder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is completely understandable to be confused at first with how to deal with state on **SwiftUI**, but hang on there, you will find your way soon enough.

What you want to do can be achieved in many different ways, depending on the requirements and limitations of your project.
I will mention a few options, but I'm sure there are more, and all of them have pros and cons, but hopefully one can suit your needs.

## Binding

Probably the easiest would be to use a `@Binding`, [here](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/swiftui/what-is-the-binding-property-wrapper) a good tutorial/explanation of it.

An example would be to have `data` declared on your `MainView` and pass it as a `@Binding` to your `ChildView`. When you need to change the `data`, you change it directly on the `MainView` and will be reflected on both.

This solutions leads to having the logic on both parts, probably not ideal, but is up to what you need.

Also notice how the `initialiser` for `ChildView` is directly on the body of `MainView` now.

#### Example

```swift
struct ChildView: View {
    
    @Binding var data: Int

     var body: some View {
       Text("\(data)")

        Button(action: update) {
            Text("update") // works as expected 
        }
     }

    func update() {
        // fetch data from external source 
        data = 42
    }
}
```

```swift
struct MainView: View {
    @State var data: Int = 0
 
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
           ChildView(data: $data)
           
           Button(action: {
              data = 42
           }) {
              Text("update")  // In fact calls the function, but doesn't set the data variable to the new value
           }
        }
    }
}
```

## ObservableObject

Another alternative would be to remove state and logic from your views, using an `ObservableObject`, [here](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/swiftui/how-to-use-observedobject-to-manage-state-from-external-objects) an explanation of it.

#### Example

```swift
class ViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var data: Int = 0

    func update() {
        // fetch data from external source 
        data = 42
    }
}
```

```swift
struct ChildView: View {
    @ObservedObject var viewModel: ViewModel

     var body: some View {
       Text("\(viewModel.data)")

        Button(action: viewModel.update) {
            Text("update") // works as expected 
        }
     }
}
```

```swift
struct MainView: View {
    @StateObject var viewModel = ViewModel()
 
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
           ChildView(viewModel: viewModel)
           
           Button(action: {
              viewModel.update()
           }) {
              Text("update")  // In fact calls the function, but doesn't set the data variable to the new value
           }
        }
    }
}
```